# How do I implement a cookiecutter project with custom shortcuts for certain commands?

Tags: python, cookiecutter

I am developing a cookiecutter template for LaTeX projects. However, I would like to implement a CLI that acts as a shortcut for certain commands. For example, the command

```
cookiecutter --no-input --replay-file ~/.cookiecutters/cookiecutter-latex/style1.json
```

could also be executed using the command

```
customtex style1
```

I had thought of making a python package that implements the CLI and also contains the template, so that the `customtex` commands (the name of the package) use the cookiecutter contained in the package source files. This way, users could also simply download the template and use it as normal.

I would like to know if this is the best way to implement what I want or if you can think of a better way to do this. I would also like to know what problems I could have doing it this way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a couple of ways you can do it, and you've hit on both.

Embedding cookiecutter in a CLI is pretty common. Databricks has a tool called "[dbx](https://github.com/databrickslabs/dbx)" that has an embedded [cookiecutter template](https://github.com/databrickslabs/dbx/tree/main/dbx/templates/projects/python_basic) in it that it uses to generate new projects. So that's a reasonable way to go.

You can also use post and pre hooks to modify behavior. My python template ([Rob's Awesome Python Template](https://github.com/tedivm/robs_awesome_python_template)) uses [post hooks](https://github.com/tedivm/robs_awesome_python_template/blob/main/hooks/post_gen_project.py) to modify the output based off of the arguments passed in by the user. This allows people to use Cookiecutter directly without installing anything else.

Comment: Perfect, that was what I wanted to know. Just one thing: when using Python hooks, which Python runs the scripts?

Comment: That's a great question- the hook gets run by the cookiecutter python. With my code I use that to generate a virtual environment, and then explicitly call into that virtual environment from the hook (via the makefile).